# Бан пользователя при заходе на сервер

Tags: python, discord.py

Как сделать что бы бот кикал определенного человека, который заходит на сервер?

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста поставьте галочку

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать список id тех людей, кого нужно **кикать при заходе:**

```
kick_id = [702338551806951466]
```

Создаём функцию **on_member_join(member)** и проверяем есть ли id зашедшего человека в нашем списке **kick_id**

**Итог:**

```
kick_id = [702338551806951466]
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.id in kick_id:
        await member.kick()
    else:
        return
```

Если нужен именно бан, замените в `await member.kick()` `kick()` на `ban()`